# Hide activity events at startup

Tags: tmux

I wrote a script to start a tmux session with specific windows and panes.

However, because I set the options `visual-activity` and `monitor-activity`, I see the text "Activity in window #" everytime I run this script and the tabs are hightlighted.
Is there a way to avoid having these indicators when starting a tmux session?

For instance, even with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux new-session -ds session

tmux set-option visual-activity off
tmux set-window-option monitor-activity off

tmux new-window test
tmux new-window -n editor -t session nano
tmux select-window -t :0

tmux set-option visual-activity on
tmux set-window-option monitor-activity on

tmux attach-session -t session
```

where the activity is turned off, I will see the indicators.

How can I turn off the indicators at tmux startup?

Comment: The problem is that the new window is running concurrently with this script. You're turning on `visual-activity` immediately after starting the new window, but that doesn't allow time for it to produce its initial output. Try putting a `sleep` command before that.

Comment: Good idea! I added a function that sleeps before turning on the options and this function is run in the background so that it does not interrupt the actual script. Please put this in an answer so that I accept it :) .

Comment: I didn't even think of the idea of running that in the background, I've put it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start another window, it runs concurrently with the original window that executed `tmux new-window`. There's no way for the original window to know when the new window is done starting up. The best you can do is estimate how long it takes for it to start up, and sleep that long in the original window before enabling `visual-activity` and `monitor-activity`. You can run it in the background so that your original startup script isn't delayed.

```
{
    sleep 2
    tmux set-option visual-activity on
    tmux set-window-option monitor-activity on
} &
```